# Can I / how can I treat a pointer to a field's member as a pointer to member?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I have to create a mapping between an enum, and the fields of my object.

```
enum E {
   FIRST,
   SECOND,
   THIRD
};

struct A {
   int i;
   int j;
};
```

I could do that the simple way with a get and set function and a switch-case, but let's suppose I'm a maniac and writing two lines instead of one for every enum value bothers me greatly.

So I create a map of enum values to pointers to members of `A`.

```
static std::map<E, int A::*> m = {
   {FIRST, &A::i},
   {SECOND, &A::j}
};
```

I am very happy with this map. I can now write succinct translation functions both ways and the performance is of little concern to me.

But, tragedy ! The executives have spoken and instead of `A`, we will now map fields to `B`, which is also a struct of ints, but this time, some of these are grouped into sub-structs.

```
struct A {
   int i;
   int j;
};

struct B {
   A a;
   int k;
   int l;
};
```

What would be a clean and non-undefined-behavior-reliant way of still creating a map of the sort ?

```
static std::map<E, int B::*> m2 = {
   {FIRST, &B::k},
   {SECOND, &B::l},
   {THIRD, /* somehow access a::i as a B::* */}
};
```

Comment: You could try and mess around with `offsetof`, but this is a really strange thing to need to do.

Comment: Alas the one who is to maintain this code... If you want to treat `i` and `j` (and `k` and `l`) as array elements, why not use an array? You can use constants as indices.

Comment: "maniac" and "clean" arent those contradicting? Imho clean would be to write a switch (and drop coding style to put each case in a single line ;)

Comment: [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/9xY3K9)'s an alternative mapping. It looks similarly horrific but "works" (until you start making changes and everything breaks down).

Comment: seriously, are you asking for a clean solution or a hack? Both have their place, but usually not in the same project ;)

Comment: You could maybe use a map of function pointers where the function takes a reference to B and returns reference to the member (of member). PS. It would be better to use an array as the map since your keys are integers starting from 0... just like array indices.

Comment: Do you mind renaming `FIRST`, `SECOND` to `_1`, `_2`?

Comment: @Sprite Not allowed if `E` is in the global namespace since those names are reserved. In a custom namespace it's fine though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a map of function pointers instead of member pointers.

Also, since your keys are integers starting from 0 and the structure is presumably not dynamic, a more efficient map is an array.

Example:

```
using get = int&(B&);
constexpr get* m[] = {
    [](B& b) -> int& { return b.k; },   // FIRST
    [](B& b) -> int& { return b.l; },   // SECOND
    [](B& b) -> int& { return b.a.i; }, // THIRD
};
```